# How to switch LDAP to Windows authentication?

Tags: web8, ldap

On SDL Web 8, a PS script (`SetupLDAP.ps1`) can be used to enable LDAP authentication.

It's quite useful, but I cannot found how to switch LDAP to Windows authentication (it means I want to return to default setting).

Is there another PS script or something to switch LDAP to Windows authentication?

Or is there any documentation to do that?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of the authentication method on the server-side is done in two `Web.config` files (one for the CM Website root and one for the `webservices` web app). These config files contain XML comments about what to change for LDAP auth and HTTPS.

You can also have a peek at `SetupLDAP.ps1` itself. It will at least show which config setting are changed. Combine that with a peek at an "original" config file and you will know how to revert.

We used to have an explicit description of what to modify where in our documentation, but that has been replaced by "run the PowerShell script" since these exist.